# AWS: Filter/Search by TAG in ECS

Tags: containers, amazon-ecs, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I have some services deployed on AWS ECS (on EC2) and environment pointed to via S3 file. I want to redeploy all the services that have some common cross-cutting environment. Say I want to re-deploy all the services for which I use a particular logging once I change some environment related to logging.

I am thinking of using tags to group related services. I see search on tags (in console) , but I don't see in cli a way to find all services given a tag (say logenabled = true). I can see listing of tags using list-tag-for-resources using ARN but my requirement is reverse (given a tag find all the resources). Is this possible.

Maybe somehting similar to one in SO for EC2 :

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId]' --filter Name=tag:TAG,Values=VALUE" --output text
```